# Software for recognizing modified images?

Tags: images, photography

Situation: Client sends a image to company (lets say we are talking about document).
Problem: Need to check if this document (in most cases we are talking about photos of documents, taken by mobile phone) has been modified (by photoshop, or just by cutting some numbers/letters out and gluing on document, scanning it and using this image...).
Solution: Find software which could check these images and try to determine that they have been edited or changed in some way. Solution should be able to be automated.

I know that there most likely aren't program which would recognize fake images with 100% accuracy (especially talking about second way of modification which I mentioned), but there should be software which could try to at least catch cases when we are talking about photoshop. So far only thing I have found out are some tools which relay primary on image metadata, but that doesn't really help in this case (because you can change that too).
Right now only plausible solution, at least which I can think of, would be some kind of neuron network, which has been "trained" for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these tools are digital forensics software and one would need to be an expert in that field in order to use it. It is expensive and it isn't automated software. The better solution, in my opinion, would be an online scanner which will automate the detection process and give you their rating. One of the popular ones is called [Izitru](http://www.izitru.com/). It was formerly known as FourMatch, a Photoshop plugin. Very user friendly and easy to use. Izitru also offers their API to be integrated into other apps.

There's also [Ghiro](http://www.getghiro.org/) an open source automated digital forensics tool. Don't know nothing about it, but it's worth checking out.